# ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int) in Python - from_gerator fails

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, numpy, api

I know this question has answers, but they are not working.

why this fails ?
(and why tensorflow has troubles in reading numpy!!)

```
def data_generator(df):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        audio = row['audio']  # Replace 'audio' with the appropriate column name from your DataFrame
        audio = np.asarray(audio).astype(np.float32)
        audio_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(audio, dtype=tf.float32)
        yield audio_tensor  # this is a tensor for sure
```

and

```
list(data_generator(sample_data));  # it is fine! the list is a list of TF tensors
```

but the generator function, when passed on the `from_generator`, will fail:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_generator, args=([sample_data]), output_signature=tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32)) # sample_data is my dataframe
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[219], line 3
      1 list(data_generator(sample_data));
      2 # Create a tf.data.Dataset from the data generator
----> 3 dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_generator, args=([sample_data]), output_signature=tf.TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32))

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py:576, in deprecated_args.<locals>.deprecated_wrapper.<locals>.new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    568         _PRINTED_WARNING[(func, arg_name)] = True
    569       logging.warning(
    570           'From %s: calling %s (from %s) with %s is deprecated and will '
    571           'be removed %s.\nInstructions for updating:\n%s',
   (...)
    574           'in a future version' if date is None else ('after %s' % date),
    575           instructions)
--> 576 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py:970, in DatasetV2.from_generator(generator, output_types, output_shapes, args, output_signature, name)
    966 # Loaded lazily due to a circular dependency (dataset_ops ->
    967 # from_generator_op -> dataset_ops).
    968 # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top,protected-access
    969 from tensorflow.python.data.ops import from_generator_op
--> 970 return from_generator_op._from_generator(generator, output_types,
    971                                          output_shapes, args,
    972                                          output_signature, name)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/from_generator_op.py:155, in _from_generator(generator, output_types, output_shapes, args, output_signature, name)
    153   args = ()
    154 else:
--> 155   args = tuple(ops.convert_n_to_tensor(args, name="args"))
    157 generator_state = dataset_ops.DatasetV2._GeneratorState(generator)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    159 def get_iterator_id_fn(unused_dummy):

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1742, in convert_n_to_tensor(values, dtype, name, preferred_dtype)
   1719 def convert_n_to_tensor(values, dtype=None, name=None, preferred_dtype=None):
   1720   """Converts `values` to a list of `Tensor` objects.
   1721 
   1722   Args:
   (...)
   1740       value.
   1741   """
-> 1742   return internal_convert_n_to_tensor(
   1743       values=values,
   1744       dtype=dtype,
   1745       name=name,
   1746       preferred_dtype=preferred_dtype,
   1747       as_ref=False)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1709, in internal_convert_n_to_tensor(values, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, ctx)
   1706 for i, value in enumerate(values):
   1707   n = None if name is None else "%s_%d" % (name, i)
   1708   ret.append(
-> 1709       convert_to_tensor(
   1710           value,
   1711           dtype=dtype,
   1712           name=n,
   1713           as_ref=as_ref,
   1714           preferred_dtype=preferred_dtype,
   1715           ctx=ctx))
   1716 return ret

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/profiler/trace.py:183, in trace_wrapper.<locals>.inner_wrapper.<locals>.wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    181   with Trace(trace_name, **trace_kwargs):
    182     return func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 183 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1642, in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, dtype_hint, ctx, accepted_result_types)
   1633       raise RuntimeError(
   1634           _add_error_prefix(
   1635               f"Conversion function {conversion_func!r} for type "
   (...)
   1638               f"actual = {ret.dtype.base_dtype.name}",
   1639               name=name))
   1641 if ret is None:
-> 1642   ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1644 if ret is NotImplemented:
   1645   continue

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:344, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function(v, dtype, name, as_ref)
    341 def _constant_tensor_conversion_function(v, dtype=None, name=None,
    342                                          as_ref=False):
    343   _ = as_ref
--> 344   return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:268, in constant(value, dtype, shape, name)
    171 @tf_export("constant", v1=[])
    172 def constant(value, dtype=None, shape=None, name="Const"):
    173   """Creates a constant tensor from a tensor-like object.
    174 
    175   Note: All eager `tf.Tensor` values are immutable (in contrast to
   (...)
    266     ValueError: if called on a symbolic tensor.
    267   """
--> 268   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
    269                         allow_broadcast=True)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:280, in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    278     with trace.Trace("tf.constant"):
    279       return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
--> 280   return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    282 g = ops.get_default_graph()
    283 tensor_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue()

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:305, in _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    303 def _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape):
    304   """Creates a constant on the current device."""
--> 305   t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    306   if shape is None:
    307     return t

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:103, in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    101     dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
    102 ctx.ensure_initialized()
--> 103 return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).
```

Where does that error come from ?

It seems on the conversion function, but it worked on the generator.
So I m lost. Is it a TF bug ?

NB:

this would work:

```
tensor_list = [tf.convert_to_tensor(row['audio'], dtype=tf.float32) for _, row in sample_data.iterrows()]
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tensor_list)
```

But I want to use a generator to reduce memory pressure.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: hi @khm, I did but unfortunately i don't recall what i did and do not have the code with me to check. however, i found great benefit in using chatgpt or alike to debug the error. if i recall well, you may want to specify the shape in the generator `output_signature=tf.TensorSpec(shape=()`, so that he knows the dimension of the tensor he has to transform the numpy vector from. it might be that it read a numpy value as a float, and so it fails. Try to tell it which is the dimension of the vector output.

Comment: @user305883 The 'use chatGPT' answer you provided worked perfectly for me. There was a typo on my code that generated the error, and chatGPT pointed this out for me.